# Allocator exception whilst using boost unordered map

Tags: c++

My program processes messages containing updates. Each message can have multiple updates.
I am using boost unordered map to store the update identifer and correspoding object on which the processing is to be done.

I do something like this.

```
unorderedUpdateMap[updateID] = processObject;
```

Normally the program works fine. But during heavy load situations (when there are lot of updates) the list probably grows to a large value and the process crashes with following  core dump.

```
 (gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fcbf562b678 in (anonymous namespace)::cpp_alloc(unsigned long, bool) () from /opt/gts/3pp/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0
#1  0x00007fcbf5635218 in tc_new () from /opt/gts/3pp/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0
#2  0x00007fcbeb7bee14 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<boost::unordered_detail::hash_node<std::allocator<std::pair<long const, mds::InstrumentData*> >, boost::unordered_detail::ungrouped> >::allocate
    (this=0x472d3b0, __n=1) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.0/../../../../include/c++/4.4.0/ext/new_allocator.h:89
#3  0x00007fcbeb7bd191 in boost::unordered_detail::hash_node_constructor<std::allocator<std::pair<long const, mds::InstrumentData*> >, boost::unordered_detail::ungrouped>::construct_preamble (
    this=0x53c67f90)
    at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/util.hpp:319
#4  0x00007fcbeb7bb2d9 in boost::unordered_detail::hash_node_constructor<std::allocator<std::pair<long const, mds::InstrumentData*> >, boost::unordered_detail::ungrouped>::construct_pair<long, mds::InstrumentData*> (this=0x53c67f90, k=@0xcab44a0)
    at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/util.hpp:267
#5  0x00007fcbeb7b9497 in boost::unordered_detail::hash_unique_table<boost::unordered_detail::map<long, boost::hash<long>, std::equal_to<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, mds::InstrumentData*> > > >::operator[] (this=0x472d3a0, k=@0xcab44a0)
    at /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/unique.hpp:203
#6  0x00007fcbeb7b787f in boost::unordered_map<long, ProcessObject*, boost::hash<long>, std::equal_to<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, ProcessObject*> > >::operator[] (
    this=0x472d3a0, k=@0xcab44a0)
```

If I further go to the allocator source (as suggested in stack trace)

```
  // NB: __n is permitted to be 0.  The C++ standard says nothing
  // about what the return value is when __n == 0.
  pointer
  allocate(size_type __n, const void* = 0)
  {
    if (__builtin_expect(__n > this->max_size(), false))
      std::__throw_bad_alloc();
    return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp))); (The line which was resonpsible for crash)
  }
```

I do not use any custom allocator within map. However our programs are linked against the tcmalloc package.
Is this a memory problem? Do I need to do some pre-allocations to be prepared for such scenario

Comment: The clearer your questions are, the more chances you have of getting good answers

Comment: "I do not use any custom allocator" and "/opt/gts/3pp/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.0" do not fit well together...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: libtcmalloc does not provide allocators. It just replaces malloc/free

Comment: @sehe: commonly those are called "allocator libraries", and as seen in his backtrace the crash originates from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are simply running out of memory.

Memory allocation appears to fail. This might be due to insufficent memory, or a leak of memory.

I suggest

```
valgrind ./mytestprogram
```

to get information on these.

You can also use

```
valgrind --tool=massif ./mytestprogram
ms_print massif* | less -SR
```

to view a memory profile showing exactly what memory gets allocated where, why and what uses up the largest portion